# Setting up Silver Bird extension for identi.ca

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, twitter, api

Silver Bird (formerly Chrome Bird) is a Google Chrome extension for tweeting directly from a browser window without going to twitter.com.

I use Silver Bird for tweeting in Chrome, but I want to use it for identi.ca.

How should I set the identi.ca APIs in the Silver Bird settings?

Comment: do you mean silverbird ?

Comment: yes . beacouse the previuse name of silver bird was chrome bird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go into Tools -> Extensions, and from there select 'Options' under the Silver Bird entry, halfway down the page you'll see a section marked 'Microblogging Service', where you can switch to identi.ca.  However, if you want to use it for both that and Twitter, I think you're out of luck.

Comment: i now this but i ask : how to set identica API`s